# Extend Activity with MapActivity and ActivityGroup

Tags: android

I'm new in Android.
How am I be able to extend an Activity with both MapActivity and ActivityGroup??

Because I need to display both a Map and a customized Tab on an Activty.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityGroup implements MapActivity
```

Somehow I'm not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To display a tab use Fragment, coz ActivityGroup is Depreciated.

Comment: How am I able to do that? I need to call this method actually: private void setupTabHost() {
  mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  mTabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
 }